# Get companion object (declared in an inner class) of generic type without instance

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

I am working on a method which is given only one piece of information: a type that extends ClassTag (this can be changed to TypeTag if strong guarantees are necessary for resolving certain parts of the type). We are not given an instance such that we can use `scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror` to obtain a `InstanceMirror` from the Scala libraries available. We are not given the arguments necessary to construct such an instance. I am only able to obtain a `RuntimeClass` of this generic type. Scala has the concept of a companion object. I want to check if the companion object of the given generic class `T` extends a specific trait `A`, cast that object as that trait, and invoke the method which is overriden by that companion object.  The current code to do what I described is below:

```
def invokeOverridenMethodOfCompanionObject[T : ClassTag]() {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.NoSymbol

  val runtimeClass = scala.reflect.classTag[T].runtimeClass
  val companion = currentMirror.classSymbol(runtimeClass).companion

  companion match {
    case NoSymbol => // do nothing
    case _ => 
      // The problem is this line
      currentMirror.reflectModule(companion.asModule).instance match {
        case s: A => s.invokeOverridenMethod
        case _ => // do nothing 
      }
  }
}
```

This approach is *almost* perfect. The problem is that if the object is not top level i.e. declared within another object or class, this method no longer works. Scala then complains and spits out this error:

```
object <objectName> is an inner module, use reflectModule on an InstanceMirror to obtain its ModuleMirror
```

The problem is I am not able to obtain the instance mirror of the symbol/type which owns the companion object. I cannot construct that instance either since I have no arguments to build a dummy constructor either. I also cannot guarantee the existence of a nullary constructor either, so gimmicks using them are off limits as well. Is there a way to accomplish my goal given these constraints?

Edit: I am aware that Java `Class` can allow a person to search up the method by name and then invoke it. I know this is possible but my solution would require passing around the object later as well. Therefore, it is a *must* for me to obtain a variable reference directly to the object. You may assume that after the code block above ends, I return the companion object constructed.

Comment: As it turns out, the reason why this doesn't work as there can exist more than one companion object for each new instance of a class as @Dima had so helpfully pointed out.

Comment: You probably want ta typeclass instead of using runtime reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works [fine](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/smlSHuXlQFOXvksbsdYMhw) when the class and its companion are both defined inside an object.

What doesn't work (commented line in that scastie) is if they are defined inside a *class*. For that, I don't think you can do much without an instance, because the objects belonging to different instances are *different* (and also have different *types*): `(new Baz.Bat == new Baz.Bat) === false`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I didn't know that declaring it inside an object would be fine. Yeah, its precisely when its inside a class that its giving me a headache. I have been digging for a long time to find an elegant answer, but it has been so far denied for me.